# Repeat print after every n prints

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a variable `n`.

Now I want to print 
`"Yes"`  `n` times
then 
`"No"` `n` times

and then repeat the entire thing over and over.

How to do this in Python in shortest possible manner.
I am looking for something succinct.

Comment: something like `print 'YES'*n` ??

Comment: And what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def Print(n, s):
    i=0
    while i<n:
        print s
        i+=1

n=3
while True:
    Print(n, 'Yes')
    Print(n, 'No')
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
while True:
    print('Yes\n' * n)
    print('No\n' * n)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
while True:
    print("Yes\n" *n,end='')
    print("No\n" *n, end='')
```

Outputs -

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
No
No
No
No
```

For Python 2.x , you should first import the print function using -

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Just note that in Python 3, `raw_input` is now `input`. The OP didn't mention what version of Python he/she used, so just in case...

Comment: Yes , correct, changed it for python 3 added a note for python 2.x . Thank you